# Strange behavior with mulitiple conditions php

Tags: php

Example one ( doesn't work):

```
<?php
$classes = get_body_class();
if (!in_array('some-class',$classes) || $secondCondition === false) { ?>
     <div> Some Content </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Example Two ( works???)

```
<?php
$classes = get_body_class();
if (!in_array('some-class',$classes)) { ?>
     <?php if ($secondCondition === false) { ?>
          <div> Some Content </div>
     <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Not sure why the first code doesn't work, even when the conditions `!in_array` or `$secondCondition === false` are met, but when I wrap one condition inside another it works?

*Notice the `$secondCondition` is defined earlier so I didn't put this part of the code because it works fine.

Comment: Can you `var_dump($classes);` and `var_dump($secondCondition);` ?

Comment: I did :) when var_dump both separately, I'm getting the expected result, based on the page I'm viewing, I just do not get why the "or" part does not work inline?

Comment: Can you show it to us ? Note : you have two `?>` at the end of your script.

Comment: fixed xtra ?> , btw I just figured out what's actually strange :  in the case 'some-class' is not present in the array - the second condition is getting ignored completely, and i see the difference in my examples, btw I need one with an "OR" condition not "AND"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get this right you want to show some content if **some-class** is not in the array `$classes` AND `$secondCondition` is `false`

Your problem is that **your two examples handles the conditions different**, if you are using the `OR` operator `||` **ONLY ONE** must be true

So I guess you are looking for the `AND` operator `&&`

Try this instead:

```
<?php
$classes = get_body_class();
if (!in_array('some-class',$classes) && $secondCondition === false) : ?>
  <div> Some Content </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Working example with your code. I initialized the variables `$classes` and `$secondCondition` for testing, play a bit with it and see the difference

**Working example:**

```
$classes = array( "other-class" );
$secondCondition = false;


if ( !in_array( 'some-class', $classes ) && $secondCondition === false ) : ?>
    <div> Some Content A</div>
<?php endif;
// in this condition only one has to be true either it is not in array or $secondCondition = false
if ( !in_array( 'some-class', $classes ) || $secondCondition === false ) : ?>
    <div> Some Content B</div>
<?php endif;
// in this example BOTH conditions have to be true, first: not in array, second: $secondCondition = false
if ( !in_array( 'some-class', $classes ) ) {
    if ( $secondCondition === false ) { ?>
        <div> Some Content C</div>
    <?php }
}
```

Comment: You're right, my the second example is actually AND, and figured out how stupid the question is, because when I keep OR and change the secondCondition to false I'm getting the right result, so there was no error, and I apologize for posting the stupid question, can I down-vote myself ?

Comment: @Darko, no question is stupid, and i don't think you can downvote yourself , also I think there is no need for that ;)

Comment: not sure who downvoted, I'm not seeing a reason you have one upvote from me

Comment: @Darko thanks for that, but normally if you downvote some answer it means that you can improve it or it's not correct, so it would be interesting to know why. But sometimes there are some drive-by downvotes without a good reason

Comment: please check my last comment above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94946/discussion-between-swidmann-and-darko).

Answer (score 0):

Your two codes are not equal.
The second one checks if your value is in an array, then checks if `$secondCondition` is false.

**If both conditions are true**, it prints the `<div>`.

Therefore, the equivalent code for this condition is not

```
(!in_array('some-class',$classes) || $secondCondition === false)
```

but

```
(!in_array('some-class',$classes) && $secondCondition === false)
```

Comment: thx, I figured that, can you please check my last comment above - the $secondCondition === false is being ignored if "some-class" is not in the array - meaning the first condition is met?

Answer (score 0):

You should use more parenthesis, and less  tags

```
<?php
  $classes = get_body_class();
  if ((!in_array('some-class',$classes)) || ($secondCondition === false)) {
    echo "<div> Some Content </div>";
  }
?>
```